# How to store data from an API in localStorage with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

My practice simple SPA with VueJS requires that I listen to an API and save some of its data in the localStorage of the browser, however I'm still not very experienced with VueJS so I don't know how to take the specific data and save it to LS so that logged users can see their info later.

The API retrieves A LOT of information, for now I only want to get the email and name of the user.

This is the code so far:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
  import jsonpAdapter from 'axios-jsonp';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        info: 'placeH',
        data: []
      }
    },
    mounted: function(){
      axios({
        url: 'APIplaceholder'
        adapter: jsonpAdapter
      }).then((res) => {

      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

My problem right now is that I don't know how to select only the specific information (the API returns a lot of info, but I only need the email and name) that I want and then save it to localStorage.

I think the best would also be to save it to a JSON file in the LS.

Comment: Then store it in local storage. I suggest you to use async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `response` object which has `data` property that represents a requested `user` as follow :

```
mounted: function(){
  axios({
    url: 'APIplaceholder'
    adapter: jsonpAdapter
  }).then((res) => {     
        localStorage["name"]=res.data.name
        localStorage["email"]=res.data.email
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`localStorage` keeps strings only. This means that `localStorage.setItem("apiData", res.data)` will store the string `"[Object object]"` in localStorage, and not the `res.data` object.

You have to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to set and get items from localStorage.

```
.then((res) => {
     localStorage.setItem("apiData", JSON.stringify(res.data));
});
```

you can get them by,

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apiData"));
```

then you can access the data using (dot) operator, For example `data.userName`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: To see if I understand this correctly: the first argument "apiData" is what will be stored, and the 2nd one res.data is the actual data taken from the API? meaning, res.data will grab say "example@example.com" and then it will be passed and saved to "apiData"?

If so, isn't there a need to .stringify this into a json?

Comment: yes you are correct. localStorage only keep strings. I updated my answer.