# Vue API data is gone on window refresh

Tags: vue.js

When I login I am redirected to secret page which needs JWT authentication. Data is loaded on secret page. And when I refresh the window - data is lost. How can I fix it?

I use eventBus to send a JWT token to sibling template.

Login view method on submit:

```
submitSignin() {
      console.log("submit!");
      this.submitted = true;
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        return; // stop here if form is invalid
      }
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", this.authData)
        .then((res) => {
          this.token = res.data.token;
          this.authData.email = "";
          this.authData.password = "";
          this.$v.$reset();
          this.successMsg = "You Sign in Successfully!";
          this.$router.push({ path: "/auth/all-users" });
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            eventBus.$emit("sendtoken", this.token);
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response.data.message);
          this.errorMsg = err.response.data.message;
        });
    },
```

SecretPage view:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "SecretPage",
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadUsers() {
      let self = this;
      eventBus.$on("sendtoken", (token) => {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:3000/auth/all-users", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(token);
            console.log(response.data.users);
            self.users = response.data.users;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadUsers();
  },
};
</script>
```

[loaded users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxmvK.png)

[image: view after windows refresh but still as loggedin]

Comment: Refreshing the browser will erase data that is living in the application without being stored locally, e.g. in a localStorage. Have you tried using one?

Comment: @HeriHeheSetiawan thank you a lot, it saved my time! I used to find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580032/how-to-store-data-from-an-api-in-localstorage-with-vuejs

Comment: SOLVED. Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580032/how-to-store-data-from-an-api-in-localstorage-with-vuejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store data from an API in localStorage with VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580032/how-to-store-data-from-an-api-in-localstorage-with-vuejs)